# Typically, what information is kept in $_SESSION?

Tags: php, session

I'm trying to understand how sessions are used in the real world.  So for example, I wonder what would typically be kept in session in the following cases:

1. Social networking site
2. Small shopping site
3. UGC site (e.g., a recipe sharing site)
4. RSS reader
5. Real time basic gaming site (say, checkers for the sake of the example.)

My main issue is understanding data that is meant to be passed as variable from php file to php file, data that should be kept in a specific global variable, and data that belongs in the superglobal `$_SESSION`.

Thank you,

JDelage

Comment: Basically, anything that needs to be persisted between page requests, but isn't volatile enough to justify hitting back-end storage to fetch fresh copies each time.

Comment: from "passed as variable" do you mean as get variable or a hidden input form variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Short answer?  Anything.

Slightly less short answer?  Data that a web application may need to keep track of over several page views (the duration of a session) but that doesn't really matter if it's not stored permanently, or shared between more than one distinct user of a site.

Answer (score 1):

you must store this...

```
$_SESSION[userid]=//user id from the database
```

anything else is a judgement call,
it doesn't matter what type of a web app it is either.

Answer (score 1):

A session variable is a server side cache for registration forms and everything that needs to be personalized and stored during a telecommunication session. That's because you can start and stop and flush sessions. Each session has an individual unique key and is stored in a directory at your server under this id. In fact you can also use sqlite or a simple text file too.